# Access Jenkins workspace files in pipeline scrpit

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm quite new to Jenkins so apologies if the question is not detailed enough but I swear I've done my own searching first.

I have a pipeline script that needs to process files that have been pulled from a SCM (git) in a previous step.
One of the parameters passed to the pipeline is a folder where all these files reside. There may be subfolders contained in this folder and I need to process those as well.

So, for example, I may pass a parameter **./my-folder** to the pipeline and **my-folder** may contain the following:

./my-folder/file1.json

./my-folder/file2.json

./my-folder/subfolder/file3.json

The `my-folder` directory will be part of the repository cloned during the build phase.

While I was developing my Groovy script locally I was doing something similar to this:

```
def f = new File(folder)
```

but this doesn't work in Jenkins given the code is running on the master while the folder is on a different node.
After an extensive research I now know that there are two ways to read files in Jenkins.

1. Use `readFile`. This would be ok but I haven't found an easy way to scan an entire folder and subfolders to load all files
2. Use `FilePath`. This would be my preferred way since it's more OO but I haven't found a way to create an instance of this class. All the approaches I've seen while searching on the internet, refer to the `build` variable which, I'm not entirely sure why, is not defined in the script. In fact I'm getting `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class: WorkflowScript`

I hope the question makes sense otherwise I'd be happy to add more details.

Thanks,

Nico

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to scan the content of a folder using the following approach:

```
sh "find ${base-folder} -name *.* > files.txt"
def files = readFile "files.txt"
```

and then loop through the lines in files.txt to open each file.

The problem is this works only for txt files. I'm still unable to open a binary file (eg: a zip file) using `readFile`